# Limit number of calls to RESTful service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jboss

we have a RESTful service deployed on multiple nodes and we want to limit the number of calls coming to our service from each client with different quota for each client per minute.
our stack : Jboss application server, Java/Spring RESTful service.

What cloud be the possible technique to implement this?

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes ago I read [a good article where the same theme was highlighted](https://dzone.com/articles/where-you-rate-limit-apis-matters). 
The idea is to move this logic into load balancing proxy and here some good reasons to do it:

1. Eliminates technical debt - If you’ve got rate limiting logic coupled in with app logic, you’ve got technical debt you don’t need. You can lift and shift that debt
2. Efficiency gains - You’re offloading logic upstream, which means all your compute resources are dedicated to compute. You can better predict
3. Security - It’s well understood that application layer (request-response) attacks are on the rise, including denial of service. By leveraging an upstream proxy with greater capacity for connections you can stop those attacks in their tracks, because they never get anywhere near the actual server.

Comment: This is the way to go. @Radi, do not solve that problem within your application or in your application server.

Answer (score 0):

If the only way to access your API is through a UI client which you manages , then you can add a check on the client code (javascript in case of web app) to make a call only when the limit is not crossed by that user. Else there is no way, since a user can always access your API and the only thing at the server level which you can do is to check whether to send an error or valid result as a part of API response.

Answer (score -1):

To limit the stack, it means you need to keep state, at least based on some specific client identification. This may require you to maintain a central counter e.g. db (cassandra) which can allow you to look up the current request count per minute, and then within a java filter, you can restrict request counts as necessary.

Or if you can track the client's session, then you can track and then use sticky session, enforcing clients to use specific node for the duration of the client session, and hence you can simply track within a java filter, the number of requests per client, and send 503 code or something more relevant.

Comment: This solution is really really bad. You need two additional database calls for each request, one to read the counter and one to update the counter. Moreover you multiply the workload for your application and your database, and chances are high that you bring down your entire system in no time.

Comment: @Matt this is a solution if you want to limit requests based on conditions such necessitated by DoS, but my read of  the question was based on a fact that, the question was geared towards quota control, allocated to each client based on some dynamic information such as pricing, which cannot be tied on an ELB, so yes, my answer still remains valid within this constraints